# How to convert a dataset object to a JSON object using .NET and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp-classic, dataset

I'm getting data into a dataset object from a database and then on the server side I want to bind the dataset to the jQuery table, but the table accepts a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object.

How do I convert the DataSet object into JSON to pass through to the jQuery table?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not get much time for search...

Comment: Does [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm) helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Newtonsofts Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) and see [this example](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer) which is using datatable serialization to JSON.